# JSON merge and override array

Tags: json, node.js

I want to merge override two json objects. The difficulty here is that the merge is in an array. The only way to know where to merge is with the "name" property.

1. Is there an easy solution to do what i want with the current structure?
2. Would you consider changing the JSON structure, like having the name as a key to ease the merging?

My main object is the following:

```
   {
    "servers": {
        "services": [
            {
                "name": "api"
                "prop1": "XXX",
                "prop2": "XXX"
            },
            {
                "name": "web"
                "prop1": "XXX",
                "prop2": "XXX"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

"web" service needs to be overrriden with:

```
{
    "servers": {
        "services": [
            {
                "name": "web"
                "prop1": "overriden value"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The result object should be:

```
{
    "servers": {
        "services": [
            {
                "name": "api"
                "prop1": "XXX",
                "prop2": "XXX"
            },
            {
                "name": "web"
                "prop1": "overriden value",
                "prop2": "XXX"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? You can iterate over array and change values which match some criteria or you can change the json structure.

Comment: Yes, this is what i have done here: http://pastebin.com/rgTVqY8X override method is using https://github.com/lukebond/json-override . This is not really pretty but it does the job

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have made a node package, it's properly a little overkill, [but it will do the job, called json_merger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json_merger):

```
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/json_merger
var json_merger = require('json_merger');

var a = {
    "servers": {
        "services": [
            {
                "name": "api"
                "prop1": "XXX",
                "prop2": "XXX"
            },
            {
                "name": "web"
                "prop1": "XXX",
                "prop2": "XXX"
            }
        ]
    }
};

var b = {
    "servers": {
        "services": [
            {
                "@match": "[name=web]",
                "prop1": "overriden value"
            }
        ]
    }
}

var result = json_merger.merge(a, b);
```

But with any decent merge tool it would perserve the indexes:

```
// This is pseudo code:
var a = [{...}, {...}, {...}]

// to override object at index 1 you should be able to do this:
merge(a, [{/*intentional empty object, so we get index up*/}, 'new value at index 1']);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, i wish i could vote up but need 15 reputation :)

Comment: @Zaibes Thats ok, its not about the upvotes etc, but about helping people.